# workflow 4.0 persistence status change

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I have submission web page, after submission i am sending the data to workflow to save it to the database this also stores the instance created by the workflow in workflow database. my expection is to have instance in DB as IDLE. and whenever i required i can reload the instance. but currently it  creates record in instance table of workflow database with executionstatus = closed and iscompleted = 1. Please let me know how to set it to IDLE(or relevant status)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the status back to idle. Your workflow started and finished and that is it. If you want your workflow to remain alive you have to make sure it do so in the workflow by adding bookmarked activities like the Receive or Delay activity. But without more info on the workflow determining what is going wrong is real hard.